# How to use Sum Function for an Array of Worksheets in VBA

Tags: vba

I have some code that is suppose to use the Sum function to add up all the values in B6 of the worksheets that are in my array and put them in B6 of my "Totals" worksheet

```
Range("B6").Value = Application.Worksheet.Sum(wkshtArray).Range("B6") 
wkshtArray= Array("Dec" & numYear, "Nov" & numYear)
```

Comment: Well I can safely assume that you are likely receiving some sort of sytax error. But you still should provide more relevant code. For example, would be nice to see the `wkshtArray` declaration, and how you assign values to it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please be sure to state your problem clearly and ask a concise question, so that the community can best help you out. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can loop the worksheet collection in `ThisWorkbook` and add the values of `B6`. This will exclude the target sheet with the `If...Then` statement

```
Sub test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, tgtWs As Worksheet, lVal As Long
    Dim tgtName As String, yearNum As String

    Do
        yearNum = InputBox("Some Text")
        If Not IsNumeric(yearNum) Then
            MsgBox "Please enter a numeric number"
            yearNum = "0"
        End If
    Loop Until CLng(yearNum) > 0

    tgtName = "YTD" & yearNum

    ' This is the ws that will contain the sum product
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Set tgtWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(tgtName)
    On Error GoTo 0

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Not ws Is tgtWs Then
            lVal = lVal + ws.Range("B6")
        End If
    Next ws

    tgtWs.Range("B6") = lVal

    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox "Sheet name [" & tgtName & "] does NOT exist!", _
            vbCritical, "Invalid Sheet Name"

End Sub
```

If your intention is to **not** exclude the target sheet from your calculations, then simply remove the `If Not ws Is tgtWs Then` line.

Comment: I'm not getting anymore error messages but when I go to the cell B6 on my "Totals" sheet, no values on the other are summed up

Comment: What is the index of this worksheet in question? You will need to either change the index of the `Set tgtWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)` to the proper index #, or use the sheet name instead.

Comment: So if the sheet name is `Sheet4` where the totals go in, then that line should look like `... = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4")`

Comment: I change the name to worksheet that I want it on, but for some reason it is giving me the error code "subscript out of range"

Comment: Are you still using your array? You shouldn't have to now. This exact code as written should work (with the exception of the sheet name). There isn't anything in the code that would raise that error. What is the sheet name and I will edit my answer and it should be as simple as copying and pasting :)

Comment: No I am not using the array. The sheet name that I want the sum product in is ("YTD" & yearNum). yearNum is a variable that is defined by the user when they enter a year in my inputbox

Comment: Sounds like your sheet name is bad then. Try this (updated) code and see what the msgbox prompts you as the sheet name (and take careful consideration whether it prompts with or without a space in the name)

Comment: Its said that [YTD2020] does not exist with no spaces, even though I was staring exactly at the sheet name. 2020 is the year that I entered.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your error. This works **[perfectly fine for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAPKl.gif)**. Maybe try adding a space after the `YTD` on this line: `tgtName = "YTD" & yearNum` just to be sure?

Comment: I really don't know what the problem is. Thanks for helping though

Comment: No they are not